# Pass through Authentication - IIS and dotNet

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, single-sign-on

Sorry to repeat a question that I have seen posted many times before.  But they don't seem to answer my circumstances.  Or the articles are for previous versions of IIS and IE

I have trying to create a landing page where a user is redirected to an Intranet.  I would like users who are part of the domain to be passed straight through to our Intranet with their Windows username (Single sign on).  However I would also like the users who do not have a user name to be passed to a login page.

The problems seems to be when Enabling Anonyomous Access on IIS.  You can allow access through to the IIS but can not detect the username and vice versa.

I have setup a solution which does something similar to this.  However when a user who is not part of the domain accesses the site then they have to click cancel to the dialogue box (Windows login).  They are then redirected to the 402 page which is a login page

Does anyone know how to stop this dialogue box being displayed?  If I can get rid of the dialogue box then this would solve my problem.

I have looked a loads of solutions which none of them have the desired effect:

- http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx
- https://community.altiusconsulting.com/blogs/konstantinshapkin/archive/2009/09/22/asp-net-mixed-authentication.aspx

(These two are the most suited match for my problem - but don't see to provide the single page and filter the user to the correct place)

Any help would be greatly Appreciated.  Let me know as well if I am asking for the impossible (I have been looking for an answer for days now...)  I seem to be hacking the iis server to do something it doesn't want to do...

I have also tried windows and forms authentication bother together which doesn't seem to work on both IIS 6.0 and 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a solution to your problem however I know for certain the you **cannot** (and should not) override the default browser behaviour you mention here:

> Does anyone know how to stop this dialogue box being displayed? If I can get rid of the dialogue box then this would solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris yes this was the answer I thought I may have got.  Just thought I would confirm my thoughts